# remove image src name back and front

Tags: javascript

i need to split those name front and back

i having this name src by click the image and i wanted to split them , i cant get what i wanted.

```
function addinner(){
     typebox.innerHTML = "<img src='http://john01/myimage.com/Img/computer1/Image1.png'>"
}
```

i need to get this text

```
Img/computer1/Image1
```

things are i need to remove whatever behide the Image1 , jpg gif png jpeg.

how i going to those text and store to variable ?

Comment: Where's your code that's supposed to at least try and solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Javascript, use the [split function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var str = "I-Love-Banana";
var res = str.split("-");
// res = ["I", "Love", "Banana"]
```

For your example, split by / and take the last entry of the array

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using the `split` method.Read more about it [here!](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var url= "<img src='http://john01/myimage.com/Img/computer1/Image1.png'>".split('/');

var image= url[4]+url[5]+(url[6].split('.')[0]);
```